# Can I use The Media Creation Tool to create installation USB drive that can be activated with Windows 10 Pro OEM key?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is it possible to use The Media Creation Tool to create installation USB drive that can be activated with Windows 10 Pro OEM key?

Comment: Yes.  Licensing comes from the licensing server.

Comment: Windows 10 and Windows 11 automatically activate. There is no such thing as an Windows 10 or Windows 11 “OEM” or “Retail” installation media

Answer (score 0):

Activating Windows 10 Pro with an OEM key is only possible on the
computer which was sold with this OEM key.

An OEM key for one computer will not work on any other computer.

In addition, there is no need to put the OEM key inside the Windows
boot media, since the activation for the original computer is
automatic the moment it contacts the Microsoft license servers
via the internet.